# how to write php code to convert latitude longitude value to address in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysqli, laravel-5

i am fetching values from the database and displaying it into a table using php laravel. Latitude logitude value am fetching and displaying in my table. there is another column address, so in that column i need to display the address by converting corresponding lat long value from the database. Can anyone tell how i can write the code for that?

my view blade is giving below

```
    @extends('app')

@section('content')
    </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper">
        <div class="templatemo-content">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
                <li class="active">Vehicle Report</li>
            </ol>
            <h1>Vehicle Report</h1>

            <p></p>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">

                        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Lat/Long</th>

                                <th>Speed</th>
                                <th>Altitude</th>
                                <th>Odometer</th>
                                <th>Fuel</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($devices as $device)
                                <tr>

                                    <td>{{ date('Y/m/d H:i:s',($device->timestamp)) }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ date('H:i:s',($device->timestamp)) }}</td>
                                    <td>{{--}}{{ $device->statusCode }}--}}
                                        @if($device->statusCode == '61715')
                                            Stop
                                        @elseif($device->statusCode=='62465')
                                            Ignition_On
                                            @elseif($device->statusCode=='61713')
                                            Start
                                        @elseif($device->statusCode=='61714')
                                            InMotion
                                        @elseif($device->statusCode=='62467')
                                            Ignition_Off

                                            @else

                                            Speeding
                                        @endif

                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{ round($device->latitude,5).'/'.round($device->longitude,5) }}</td>

                                    <td>{{ $device->speed }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ round($device->altitude) }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ round($device->odometer) }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ ($device->fuelLevel*100).'%' }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ ?????????? }}</td>


                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br>





    </br></br></br></br>
```

Controller page is

```
 class ReportController extends Controller
{
    public $type = 'Device';


    public function getAdd()
    {
        $vehicles = DB::table('device')->get();
        return view('reports.vehicleDetail')->with('vehicles', $vehicles);
    }


    public function get(Request $request)
    {

        $account = Account::select('accountID')->where('accountID','=','gts')->get();


        foreach ($account as $acc) {
            $abc = $acc->accountID;
        }





        try {
            $device_id = $request['deviceID'];
            $from = strtotime($request['Fdate']);
            $to = strtotime($request['Tdate']);


            $devices=DB::table('device as b')
                ->join('eventdata as a', 'a.deviceID', '=', 'b.deviceID')
                ->where('a.deviceID', '=', $device_id)
                ->where('a.accountID', '=', $abc)
                ->where('a.creationTime', '>=', $from)
                ->where('a.creationTime', '<=', $to)
                ->select('a.accountID', 'a.deviceID', 'b.description', 'a.timestamp','a.statusCode',
                    'a.latitude', 'a.longitude', 'a.speedKPH as speed', 'a.heading', 'a.altitude', 'a.address', 'a.distanceKM as distance', 'a.odometerKM as odometer', 'a.IbatVolts', 'a.EbatVolts', 'a.ITempr', 'a.fuelLevel', 'a.inputState', 'a.IgnRuntime', 'GPSFixType', 'a.GPSPDOP', 'a.isTollRoad')->get();




//            $devices = DB::table('eventdata')->get();
            return view('reports.vehicleReport')->with('devices', $devices);




        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $err) {
            //Show error page
        }

    }




}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Reverese Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#ReverseGeocoding). Google maps API would be the best choice.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['latitude'])){
    $lat=$_POST['latitude'];
    $long=$_POST['longitude'];
    $address=file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
    $json_data=json_decode($address);
    $full_address=$json_data->results[0]->formatted_address;
  }
?>
```

Comment: i am adding my controller page in my question

Comment: u r ryt.. (Y).. i am fetching lat long from the DB, so for demo purpose i need to show the address of each lat long. already am taking all the values in to one variable. so from that variable, need to take lat long.  So is that possible to use this code inside that function?.How can i take that lat long to this function.?  Actually am new in laravel framework. Hope you can help me out from this problm

Comment: yes u can just replace the $lat  $long variables with the values you fetch from database

Comment: Also see this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses to understand the api response

Comment: here we are storing converted address value in full_address variable, right?. how can we fetch each value from that array?. inside @foreach what code will write?